# Center div with inline link elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a div with inline links within it. However I am not having any luck. Here is my attempt:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s8mq2vx5/)

HTML:

```
<div class="help-buttons">
    <a href="#" class="help-button">User Information</a>
    <a href="#" class="help-button">Company Information</a>
    <a href="#" class="help-button">Driver Information</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.help-buttons {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.help-button {
  background: #1795db;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-family: 'Open sans';
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  margin: 0 30px;
 }
```

Comment: Here you go, I updated your example http://jsfiddle.net/s8mq2vx5/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the CSS for .html-buttons to:

```
.help-buttons {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/s8mq2vx5/1/)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to specify a width - or even if you do :) - you can center it with `display: table` and `margin: 0 auto;`.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/s8mq2vx5/3/)

CSS

```
.help-buttons {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---

If you wanted to, you could enhance this with `display: table-cell` on the buttons so that they will not overlap when the viewport width gets too small.

`border-collapse:separate;` and `border-spacing:20px;` give them some spacing.

[Second fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/s8mq2vx5/10/)

CSS

```
.help-buttons {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:20px;
}
.help-button {
    background: #1795db;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font-family: 'Open sans';
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin: 0 30px;
    display: table-cell;
}
```